# Using DotNet.Highcharts create multiple chart type and save it as image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnethighcharts

I am able to create a chart at the controller using DotNet.Highcharts.
Can anyone help how to save chart as image and how to add different types of charts in the container and call it in the view.

Or is there any other way to create a chart at server side and convert it to image and return the image to the view?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the Highcharts "Export" module:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that and provide me an example.